# Validating whether PDF ICC profile has been set correctly

Tags: pdf, color-profile, color-management

We received a bug from one of our customers that our printed PDFs aren't in CMYK colors. We've made some changes so that's addressed.

But our testing team wants to be able to validate whether a PDF has a CMYK color. Is there a way to validate this without the Adobe pro version and without writing any custom scripts?

Comment: "without the Adobe pro version and without writing any custom scripts" ...doesn't this mean that you search for real magic?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to do what was needed with Inkscape.